# ¿Algún simulador para IPHONE?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode, iphone

Me gustaría saber si alguien conoce algún simulador de IPHONE en el que se le pueda probar la Cámara.

Comment: Te sugiero que busques en la red, Google es tu amigo.

Comment: mala sugerencia, ya busque y sigo buscando...

Comment: ¿Y no puedes usar el que trae xcode?  Supongo que ha de traer uno nativo

Comment: Por lo que he leído es que no puedes usar la cámara en el simulador, necesitarías usar un dispositivo real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El único simulador disponible y válido es el de Xcode. Para poder probar la cámara, deberás utilizar un dispositivo real, es la única forma.
En el simulador, únicamente podrás probar el carrete.

Comment: :'( muchas gracias :'(

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez en otras plataformas como Android, Blackberry, Windows se pueden usar emuladores, en el caso de iOS los únicos que se usan como lo commentan, son los que provee el XCode. El uso de el feature de la cámara únicamente como se comenta es mediante un dispositivo físico.